# Send a pm from discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to figure out how to send a pm from a discord.py rewrite bot. I can't do ctx.author.send("context") because it messaging someone other than the author of the message.
here's the code that I have so far when I'm searching for a user it always comes with the value of NONE

```
@bot.command()
async def spam(ctx, author, message, amount):
print(author)
print(ctx.author)
victim = bot.get_user(author)
print(victim)
if not (victim == None):
    for i in range(int(amount)):
        await victim.send(message)
else:
    print("NOPE")
```

It has the out put of

```
GIMMY READY......
Denard#0759
Denard#0759
None
NOPE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to resolve the `User` object of your `victim` automatically.

```
@bot.command()
async def spam(ctx, victim: discord.User, amount, *, message):
    for _ in range(amount):
        await victim.send(message)
```

You can then use their name, id, or a mention to specify them:

```
!spam Denard 1 spam spam spam
!spam @Denard 1 spam spam spam
!spam 1234 1 spam spam spam
```