# How can I send a message specifically to the user's private channel (DM)?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How can I send a message specifically to the user's private channel?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978648/send-a-pm-from-discord-py-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
await ctx.author.send(message_here)
```

It'll send the content of the variable message_here.

It works the same way as other .send()s in the respect of it still returns a message and you can send embeds and add a delete_after.

Comment: The `.send()`s are all implementations of the [`Messageable` abstract base class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable)